# looking for good django 1.8 resources to begin with

Tags: django

I've been desperately searching on internet for where to start learning django 1.8,I am  absolutely new to django and looking for good django books.is django documentation suffice to master django.how should i go over documentation if it is ample where should I start in documentation.obviously djangobook was one thing I found good,but it was altogether obsolete.help me out I am suffocating with confusion please throw some light on my mystery ,direct me.

Answer (score 3):

[Two Scoops of Django 1.8](http://twoscoopspress.org/products/two-scoops-of-django-1-8) is available as an early release PDF right now, and they are going to be releasing a paperback by [mid-to-late May 2015](http://twoscoopspress.org/pages/two-scoops-of-django-1-8-faq#what-formats). The PDF just received its second update.

I have personally purchased Two Scoops of Django 1.5 and 1.6 separately, and would recommend this book to anyone. It shows you many best practices. My current workplace will be ordering 1 copy of [Two Scoops of Django 1.8](http://twoscoopspress.org/products/two-scoops-of-django-1-8) per developer, because it is an excellent resource we are going to use for on-boarding and training.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with tango-with-django.
Although the specific version in on 1.7 for this book,
it still remains relevant

Here is the link:
http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/

Comment: excellent coincidence that is what i've been looking at now trying to get reviews on the book you suggested thanks any way,going over it right now.sorry I'm worse off in reputation cant upvote your reply

Comment: thanks for your reply found that one good!!

Answer (score 0):

The official tutorial would be the best place to start.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/

Most versions are fairly compatible, so unless you are looking at really old tutorials you shouldn't need to worry too much about the version.

Comment: thanks for your reply.saved my day by saying the important fact that version is not crucial,that was one thing I was about to ask.

Comment: one question that I was about to ask was ,had it got anything to do  version,and your reply helped me. so are there any substantial differences between 1.0 and 1.8 according to you?.would you suggest going over 1.0 now(djangobook with 1.0 impressed me that's why i'm asking).or would you want me to go with your link.

Comment: Between 1.3 and 1.4 were some larger changes. A lot of stuff got moved from function based views to class based views. Having a quick look over the book, I guess most of it is still relevant, but the generic views may have changed a fair bit.